# Bolding elements of a 2d array in AWT

Tags: java, awt

I have a 2-d Array of buttons, the labels of these buttons change and are displayed as they change.  There are certain buttons that are static and do not change throughout the duration of the program, I'm looking to make the text of these buttons bold.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following:

```
    Button[][] buttons = new Button[][]{{}}; // fill your buttons array

    for (Button[] bb : buttons) {
        for (Button b : bb) {
            if (BUTTON SHOULD BE BOLD) {
                Font font = b.getFont();
                Font bold = new Font(font.getName(), Font.BOLD, font.getSize());
                b.setFont(bold);
            }
        }
    }
```